# Summing Values based on Grouping

Tags: sas

Consider the following data set  `test` :

```
 Drug  Quantity State Year
  A     
  B
  C
  .        .      .     .
```

How would I sum up the quantities of each drug grouped by state and year? Would it be something like:

```
 data test;
 by Drug State Year;
 Total = sum(Quantity)
 run;
```

Comment: No, look into proc means instead.  You may want to consider taking the SAS Programming 1 course available on SAS website for free.

Comment: Search for a tutorial on SQL (if you don't already know it), and then how to use SQL in SAS.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
data test;
    input Drug $ Quantity State $ Year;
    datalines;
    A 10 NY 2013
    A 20 NY 2014
    B 110 NY 2013
    B 210 NY 2014   
    A 50 OH 2013
    A 60 OH 2014
    B 150 OH 2013
    B 260 OH 2014       
    A 22 NY 2014
    B 100 OH 2013
    ;
RUN;


proc means data= test SUM MAXDEC=0;
   class Drug State Year;   
   var Quantity;
RUN;
```

Comment: Why no decimals...? I don't think I've ever seen a good reason to use `maxdec` (not to say there isn't one).

Comment: in this case the reason was a lot of 0s. `MAXDEC=number
specifies the maximum number of decimal places to display the statistics in the printed or displayed output. MAXDEC= has no effect on statistics that are saved in an output data set.` As per [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/a000146729.htm#a003281436)

Comment: I'm familiar with the option and what it does, but it seems like a bad idea when you aren't saving it to a dataset because the numbers may be misleading. IMO too many zeroes is better than blind rounding.

Comment: In this case (show a way to aggregate data) the 0s were just a noise. Probably I spend too much time with final users and they don't like this kind of stuff

Answer (score 1):

Mucio answer is good, but if you are after SAS SQL version, here it is:

```
data test;
    input Drug $ Quantity State $ Year;
    datalines;
    A 10 NY 2013
    A 20 NY 2014
    B 110 NY 2013
    B 210 NY 2014   
    A 50 OH 2013
    A 60 OH 2014
    B 150 OH 2013
    B 260 OH 2014       
    A 22 NY 2014
    B 100 OH 2013
    ;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE EGTASK.QUERY_FOR_TEST AS 
   SELECT t1.Drug, 
          t1.State, 
          t1.Year, 
          /* SUM_of_Quantity */
            (SUM(t1.Quantity)) AS SUM_of_Quantity
      FROM WORK.TEST t1
      GROUP BY t1.Drug,
               t1.State,
               t1.Year;
QUIT;
```

Result:

[image: Result]